# GD error while try load font

Tags: php, image, fonts, gd

I try load font by [imageloadfont](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageloadfont.php) function. When I running script I receive error:

```
gd warning: product of memory allocation multiplication would exceed INT_MAX, failing operation gracefully
PHP Warning:  imageloadfont(): Error reading font, invalid font header
```

What can cause this problem?

Env:

Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit

PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem wasn't in the imageloadfont function.

I was trying to load the font (.ttf) to imageloadfont and set it on the image. Instead of using the imagestring function, I now used imagettftext to load the custom font and place the string on the picture.

Comment: The solution is not to use the bugged function and use another instead?

Answer (score 3):

I saw this error while trying to randomly use one of the system's .ttf file.
The PHP Manual example has .gdf font file.

My image dimensions are 1013 x 638 (646294 pixels), an ID card sized image in 300 dpi.

PHP_INT_MAX in my case has a value of 2147483647 and memory limit set to 128 MB.

The converted new font file worked (.gdf format font)

**Font converter**: www.wedwick.com/wftopf.exe

Source: http://www.animeviews.com/article.php?ID=263